# Python Multiprocessing when converting pdf to text

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, apache-tika, pdftotext

I am trying to implement multiprocessing with my pdf to text converter to run the converter parallel across multiple languages. For text conversion I use the tika port for python as it seems to very reliably convert the pdf (better than pdfminer3k etc.). 
I am using the following code

```
import tika
from tika import parser

def parse_pdf(file):
    path_to_pdf = directory + "/" + file
    # Convert PDF to text
    parsed = parser.from_file(path_to_pdf,'http://tika:9998/tika')
    text = str(parsed["content"]).strip('\n')
    return text

#List of languages
languages=["English", "Finnish", "French"]

def pdf_to_text(lang):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if lang in file:
            nr_docs+=1
            print(lang,file)
            text=parse_pdf(file) 
            ...
#Multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=mp.Pool()
    results = [pool.map(readability, languages)]
    print(results)
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bottle neck with tika as I get the following error:

> requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:  HTTPConnectionPool(host='tika', port=9998): Max retries exceeded with url: /rmeta/text (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that? My system should be powerful enough (32 Cores, 64 RAM)...

Comment: Looks like it's failing to resolve the IP address for the host-name `tika`

Comment: @Himal Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Do you have `tika` in your `hosts` file ? can you access http://tika:9998/tika from browser ? Also, try using the IP address instead if it's possible (in your script).